# Extended game-form with egameps.sty: no branches

Tags: pstricks

I'm trying to learn to create extended game-forms with LaTeX, but I don't get branches. The example code I've downloaded is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{egameps}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{egame}(600,280)
\putbranch(300,240)(2,1){200} \iib{1}{$C$}{$D$}
\putbranch(100,140)(1,1){100} \iib{}{$c$}{$d$}[$3,3$][$1,4$]
\putbranch(500,140)(1,1){100} \iib{}{$c$}{$d$}[$1,4$][$2,2$]
\infoset(100,140){400}{2}
\end{egame}
\hspace*{\fill} \caption[]{Sample Game}\label{mygame}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I only get this:

[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: This runs fine for me with `XeLaTeX` so you must not be processing the file correctly. Also, if you are not already committed to using `egameps`, you should have a look at `tikz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`egameps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/egameps) uses [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) to draw the lines between nodes. As such, you require a `latex`>`dvips`>`ps2pdf` or `xelatex` compilation sequence to obtain a PDF as output.

[image]

For drawing something similar *directly* in PDF, you could consider using [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). There are numerous examples on this site, or you can follow the rich [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package is based on `TikZ` and designed to draw extensive game trees. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(0)[initial node]{1}
  \istb{C}[al]       \istb{D}[ar]       \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{30mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1)
  \istb{c}[al]{3,3}  \istb{d}[ar]{1,4}  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2)
  \istb{c}[al]{1,4}  \istb{d}[ar]{2,2}  \endist
\xtInfoset(1)(2){2}
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```